# Find the most popular element from a row in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I want to create a new column that is populated by the most popular element in the four rows mentioned
(I have more than 4 rows in the dataset).

```
Initial df
index | lang_langid | lang_langdetect | pycld2 | pycld3 | 
   0  |      en     |        ru       |   ru   |   ru   |
   1  |      de     |        it       |   it   |   fr   | 
   2  |      es     |        es       |   sg   |   sg   |
   3  |      mt     |        mt       |   mt   |   mt   |
```

```
Expected df
index |lang_langid  | lang_langdetect | pycld2 | pycld3 | text_language |
   0  |      en     |        ru       |   ru   |   ru   |     ru        |
   1  |      de     |        it       |   it   |   fr   |     it        |
   2  |      es     |        es       |   sg   |   sg   |     un        |
   3  |      mt     |        mt       |   mt   |   mt   |     mt        |
```

The most popular element in the first row is "ru" as it appears 3x, whereas "en" only 1x.
Second row, most popular element is "it" as it appears 2x, whereas "de" and "fr" only 1x.
Third row, both "es" and "sg" are elected twice, so the expected output is "un" for unknown.
Fourth row, all values are "mt".
How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
m = df.mode(1)
df['text_language'] = np.where(m.count(1)>1,"un",m.iloc[:,0])
```

---

```
print(df)

      lang_langid lang_langdetect pycld2 pycld3 text_language
index                                                        
0              en              ru     ru     ru            ru
1              de              it     it     fr            it
2              es              es     sg     sg            un
3              mt              mt     mt     mt            mt
```